# How do you search for a folder in outlook 2016?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2016

I have a client who organizes things in his outlook by folder. Subsequently, he now has  several hundred if not 1000 folders. It takes forever for him to scroll through and find the folder that he wants, so he wants to be able to search for a folder by name.

This is different than searching for an I mail and displaying the folder! In his case, he has different projects that he's working on and the folder for that project his name something special like "Foo project in Gotham City."

He wants to be able to search for "foo project" or "Gotham city" and find that folder. Thus, he would have access to all the contents of the folder which will be all the things he's filed in it before.

It seems like that should be doable however, the only thing I can find on the Internet is how to display the folder that contains an email search result, not how to display only folder names in the results regardless of the folder content.

How do I do the search?

Comment: Outlook will only search for mail.  Outlook doesn't have the ability to search for folders.  It sounds like your client should should their organization habits.

Comment: Yeah... they should be using categories...

Comment: You could filter Categories.  You might even be able to add something like categories through an add-on.  you might be able to create a add-on to search for folder names all depends if this client is worth it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the commercial [Quick Folders](https://www.reliefjet.com/Quicks/Features/QuickFolders) product to search for required folders. Just type the part of its name and that's it. Please note that I'm one of the developers.

Comment: Thims... You may want to take a look at the mobile version of your website. I don't want to say anything negative, I'm just trying to help. I'm using Chrome on a Samsung s8 and it's bad. Let me know when you see this and I'll delete it.

Comment: @Fixitrod, actually we don't have the mobile version of our website.